# How to return the SKSpriteNode within given constraints following an event?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

Suppose the following:

- You have a myriad of `SKSpriteNode`s in the view.
- When the user taps the screen, you want the whatever sprite that is in / near a specific location to do an animation.

**Question**: How can figure out which `SKSpriteNode` is at the specific location *without* looping through all sprites?

For this, I have implemented a `SKSpriteNode`, *box*, which is transparent and has a texture which covers the span of the specific location, and is positioned accordingly.

The `SKSpriteNode` methods `contains` and `intersects` seem promising, but require that I pass a point or a sprite respectively.

**Question**: How can I get a `SKSpriteNode` to report what sprite, if any, it intersects with? Again, *without* looping through every sprite. If two sprites intersect with *box*, then return only that which is most prominently intersecting with *box*.

Diagram:
This is not my actual use case, but illustrates the point. There are a lot of sprites (more than visualized below) and there is an area of interest that:

- if the user touches, and
- a sprite is in that area

I want to know what sprite is there.

[image]

Comment: Wait, so when user taps, it can happen two things. He tapped on a sprite, or he tapped in a void, right? In first case, you're good. You get your sprite, right? So the second case is the problem because you don't want to loop through all sprites and based on their distance from the touch point, to return the first node that satisfies some criteria (distance criteria) ?

Comment: You are always going to have to loop through all the sprites. Without checking every sprite, how can you know whether a node intersects with the box?

Comment: And few more questions... 1) When you say SKSpriteNode box, do you mean you made something like quadrants (in order to check intersection with sprites that could be found in a current quadrant) ? 2) Does sprites change their position, eg. move from one quadrant to another? 3) What is actually wrong with looping, do you have performance problems? Also keep in mind that having sprites in an array and looping through that would be more pefromant in compare to looping through a whole node tree. Still, in your case, this sounds to me like an premature optimisation.

Comment: @Sweeper I was hoping for attaching an event and then having the event trigger when a sprite was in the location, rather than having to constantly look at all the sprites. Especially because there are a lot of them.

Comment: @Whirlwind I think you misunderstand. The tapping is independent of the sprit. The tap can happen anywhere. There is a location on the screen, say a box, which, if a sprite happens to be in the box when the user taps, you want to retrive

Comment: @Whirlwind 1.) I have an SKSpriteNode with a texture that looks is essentially just a rectangle with a border. I want to know when a sprite is in the border. 2.) the sprite are rapidly changing their position via a dynamic algorithm 3.) If the user taps a lot, then each time would require a loop until finding a sprite (if any) in the box, again there are a lot of sprites, so this would be bad. They are in an array.

Comment: @SumNeuron Okay, but how box relates to the sprite(s) ? Define "in" ? Is it a sprite a child of a box?

Comment: @Whirlwind the sprite is a box (a texture), SKSpriteNodes have the method, intersects with. "in" means that an SKSpriteNode intersects with the box SKSpriteNode

Comment: Can you draw a diagram of what you're trying to describe? It's very hard to conceptualise this from the words, and I don't think a great writer could help. It's a really visual thing, I think.

Comment: @Confused diagram added

Comment: @SumNeuron answer added...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this without SOMETHING looping through the sprites. That's either:

- The physics engine, as [Stoneburner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41666814/2109038) suggests
- The scene, via update() setting flags on sprites when they're in the
  region
- Your code that handles the touch, searching for sprites in the region

GameplayKit offers some optimisations on doing this sort of thing: https://developer.apple.com/reference/gameplaykit/gkrtree

Answer (score 1):

1. Attach a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the view
2. On tap state UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized get the location of the tap using `CGPoint pointInView = [tapper locationInView:mySKScene.view]`
3. Convert from the view's coordinate system to the scene's coordinate system using `CGPoint pointInScene = [mySKScene convertPointFromView:pointInView]`
4. Get the node at that point by asking the scene.  `SKNode *touchedNode = [self nodeAtPoint:pointInScene];`

Comment: Hey Jon, I think you misunderstand, I do not want the sprite at the tap location, I want the sprite in a specified location (elsewhere), if there is a sprite at that location when the user taps. Only the instance at which the user tap influences whether or not a sprite may be in the region, not where the user taps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SKPhysicsBodies` to detect collisions (overlaps).

Assign physicsbodies to all sknodes, add one dynamically on the region you want to detect sknodes inside, handle the `SKPhysicsContactDelegate`, remove the body again

Comment: Why use SKPhysicsBodies? That would impact the movement of sprites yes?

Comment: @SumNeuron You want to avoid writing a loop. At the time it wasn't clear this was a performance optimisation strategy you're looking for. SKPhysics removes the need to use a hand written loop, as its doing the looping within the physics engine, removing the need for you to write it. But it's probably more overhead than your own loop using GameplayKit optimisations like QuadTree.

Comment: @SumNeuron adding SKPhysicsBodies alone would not impact any movement.